# Maven accessing private repository on bitbucket

Tags: maven, bitbucket

I'm setting up maven repository for our project that is bitbucket private repository (following [this blog](http://activeintelligence.org/blog/archive/hosting-maven-repository-for-third-party-jars-on-git-bitbucketgithub/) ).

The problem is that maven 3.1.1 can not access private repository using basic auth. It downloads .pom as html with login request.

repository definition:

```
    <repository>
        <id>project-maven-repo</id>
        <url>https://bitbucket.org/company/maven-repo/raw/master/repository/</url>
    </repository>
```

Authentication from .m2/settings.xml:

```
<settings>
    <localRepository/>
    <interactiveMode/>
    <usePluginRegistry/>
    <offline/>
    <pluginGroups/>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>project-maven-repo</id>
            <username>bitbucketuser</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
        <proxies/>
    <activeProfiles/>
    <profiles/>
</settings>
```

Accessing resource using curl and basic auth works just fine. It also returns 401 response when using curl without login/password so bitbucket side seems to work as expected.

```
curl -v -u bitbucketuser:password https://bitbucket.org/company/maven-repo/raw/master/README
```

I suspect it has something to do with realm returned.

Comment: The naming of the id in the `settings.xml` file should be in accordance with the id in the pom file (repository). Otherwise Maven can't get the information about the credentials.

Comment: Updated the question, its not a problem here.

Answer (score 5):

After trying many options, the only approach that works is preparing and sending Basic Auth header manually (from [this link](http://synergian.github.io/wagon-git/bitbucket.html) )

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>project-maven-repo</id>
            <configuration>
                <httpHeaders>
                    <property>
                        <name>Authorization</name>
                        <!-- Base64-encoded "bitbucketuser:password" -->
                        <value>Basic Yml0YnVja2V0dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==</value>
                    </property>
                </httpHeaders>
            </configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

Comment: Man thank you very much for this info, I didn't noticed that headers can also be configured for servers. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the repository differently

```
<repository>
  <id>your-repo-id</id>
  <name>Your Repo Name</name>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <url>https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/yourbitbucketusername/your-bitbucket-repo/raw/your-branch</url>
</repository>
```

Have a look at http://synergian.github.io/wagon-git/bitbucket.html as well